# Reopen file for appending

Tags: python, python-2.7

There is something I'm not understanding about file output. I want to open a file, write to it, close it, then reopen it, append, close.

I don't want keep the file open the entire time the script is running.

All I ever see in the file is the *** Start ***. I want to see the fail messages and the **Complete** message.
How do I do this?

```
log_failed_download_file = open(log_failed_download_filename, "w")
log_failed_download_file.write ("\n*** Start ***");
log_failed_download_file.close()

# other logic (os.chdir)

for x in range(start_x, end_x + 1): 
    # do stuff, possibly set download_error to False
    if (download_error == False):
        log_failed_download_file = open(log_failed_download_filename, "a")
        log_failed_download_file .write(url)
        log_failed_download_file .close()

# other logic

log_failed_download_file = open(log_failed_download_filename, "a")
log_failed_download_file.write ("\n\nComplete - %r" % str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%Y  %H:%M:%S')))
log_failed_download_file.close()
```

Edit:
I've added that `os.chdir` is in the "other logic" part because that is the source of the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the code is running?

Comment: Yes. I just made correction that might have been the cause of your concern.

Comment: If you print instead of write to a file is it calling those lines?

Comment: Yes. I actually have print statements, I just removed them to make the question more succinct.

Comment: The code you've posted should work as you've intended. Perhaps there's something else going on in the code you've not posted.

Comment: How do you know it's not writing to the file? Can you read it in again at the end and print the contents?

Comment: When the script is finished, I open the txt file in a text editor and see the contents which is only the ***Start***

Comment: @AlLelopath How do you know that's the file you're writing to?

Comment: @AlLelopath don't you open the file later again?

Comment: @Peter Wood: Because of the date/time on the file in the File Explorer (Windows 10)

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: UltraEdit, Notepad.

Comment: @Pawei Kordowski: I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I have another file open for writing for the duration of the script. Does this matter?

Comment: @AlLelopath Maybe the editor isn't updating its display

Comment: @Peter Wood: I understand what you are saying. I open and close the txt file to make sure that is not the problem.

Comment: In your script print `os.path.abspath(log_failed_download_filename)`

Comment: @Peter Wood:Whoa ... you have focussed in on the problem. The path of the file on the first open is C:\a\b and then on the second open it is C:\a\b\c. Not sure why yet. Somehow the "base" directory is being changed.

Comment: If you call `os.chdir` and the log filename you use isn't the full path, you'll write to the different directory instead of the original working directory.

Comment: That's it. Please post an answer to that effect and I'll checkmark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `log_failed_download_filename` is just the name of the file, changing the current working directory will change where you write to. So you are getting half the log written to one place, then the rest written to another after you call `os.chdir`.

To avoid this, you can make your filename into the whole filepath:

```
log_path = os.path.abspath(log_failed_download_filename)
```

This gives the absolute path to the file. From the documentation for [**`os.path.abspath`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath):

> Return a normalized absolutized version of the pathname path. On most platforms, this is equivalent to calling the function `normpath()` as follows: `normpath(join(os.getcwd(), path))`.

Once you call `os.chdir`, `os.getcwd` could return something different, so `abspath` would also be different.

Just to note, modern Python opens files using the `with` context manager. This automatically closes files for you:

```
with open(log_path, 'w') as log:
    log.write("\n*** Start ***")

# other logic (os.chdir)

for x in range(start_x, end_x + 1): 
    # do stuff, possibly set download_error to False
    if not download_error:
        with open(log_path, 'a') as log:
            log.write(url)

# other logic

with open(log_path, 'a') as log:
    log.write("\n\nComplete - %r" %
               str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%Y  %H:%M:%S')))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge, the python function to write a file, creates a new file to write on to it. So every time you use .write function it creates a file and writes whatever you put on the parameter and if you use and existing file and write to it, it will erase its initial contents and write the additional information.

In your case, the program goes through the first write statement and never reaches the next ones because logically if your program was perfect it would create multiple files in your directory.

Comment: They're using the `'a'` flag which appends to the file and doesn't overwrite if the file already exists.

Comment: He's using `"a"` mode which appends to a file; this will not erase its initial contents.

Comment: @PeterWood I am sorry, I havent seen that.

Comment: Check [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use something like the `log` function from down below:

```
def main():
    a = 1
    log('my_log.txt', 'Hello', 'World')
    a += 1
    log('my_log.txt', 'a =', a)


def log(path, *objects):
    with open(path, 'at') as file:
        print(*objects, file=file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```